# MySQL wildcards workaround needed

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

Ok so the main problem is a poorly designed php script.. but I cant do any thing about that right now..

So I turn to you for some help! :)

I want to list all items that start with "a%".. easy!.. well not here.. by default the search is made with wildcards "%string%".

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Select2` FROM `items` WHERE `Select2` LIKE "%a%"
```

And I can´t change the search script... :/

Is there anyway that you can think of to get me around this problem?

Comment: If the search query is subject to SQL injection you could get around it, but that is obviously a very bad idea. I think you are SOL.

Comment: I´m quite new to SQL.. could you explain some more? "is subject to SQL injection"?

Comment: You want to change the results returned by an SQL query without changing the query. I'd like to think that even someone new to SQL could see the flaw in this approach. I'm struggling to work out what RedFilter's cunning plan is (actually I can think of several ways to change the results without changing the query - but none which would address the specific question asked here, and all of which are very complex). BTW Mackelito, if you're responsible for the code running on this site, then you should start learning a little about website security; www.owasp.org is a good starting point.

Comment: If the server throws an error (or perhaps blank screen) when you search using a search string with a single apostrophe in it, then it is subject to [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). This means you can manipulate the SQL command that gets executed, and do bad things.

Comment: If you can't change the script, it's not the question for developers forum, rather for the forum of the users of this application...

Comment: Well.. my hope was if there where some trick to sort of revoke the logic of the query... but it was a longshot ;) Sorry.. I read to fast (and I´m way to tired haha).. of course I know what SQL injections are :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get around something hardcoded like that. But, since the results will include the results you are looking for, as well as substring matches, you can filter out the substring matches on the application side.